# Adding a pointer field to a subclass of PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'd like to add a pointer field to my PFUser subclass, managed by the PFUser subclass. Ideally, the pointer object would be available automatically on the PFUser subclass - saved and fetched when the user is saved and fetched.

With any other PFObject subclass, I would simply add a Dynamic property and be sure to use includeKey when querying.

However, for a PFUser subclass, I'm never actually querying. How can I force the pointer object to fetch?

Comment: Have u used PFUser *userObjRef = [PFUser currentUser]; for getting reference to PFUser..!

Comment: I have reference to the current user, what I need is reference to a pointer object stored in a column on the User.

Comment: NSString *columnIdStr = [userObjRef objectForKey:@"column_id_Ref"];
Is it helpful..!
Here columnIdStr is the reference...!

Comment: That works for a String column, I have a Pointer column - and I'd like to fetch the underlying object complete with fields on that object.

Answer (score 4):

It's an easy, two-step process in objective-c, even with a subclassed :

1. Create a local object that represents the pointer, even though you don't have the data yet
2. Use `fetchIfNeededInBackground` to populate the pointer object locally

   ```
   PFObject *yourPointerObject = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey"pointerKey"];
   [yourPointerObject fetchIfNeededInBackground];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to PFUser

```
PFUser *userObjRef = [PFUser currentUser];
```

Getting Object reference

```
NSString *columnIdStr = [userObjRef objectForKey:@"column_id_Ref"];
```

Fetching the underlying object related to column_id

```
[[PFUser currentUser] refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    [[object objectForKey:@"column_id_Ref"] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            self.nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"obj_name_ref"];
        }
    }];

}];

[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        [[object objectForKey:@"column_id_Ref"] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error){
                self.nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"obj_name_ref"];
            }
        }];

    }];
```

Hope it helps you...!